# How to store hex data in a variable for sending over socket in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, remote-server

I have a device which will understand only hex command. I have hex command (ie 01030064007A85F6), I tried a lot to write this data over socket but the device ignores it (because it will not accept invalid data). Now I want to know that how can I store this value in a variable (or array, buffer) and then write it over the socket, so that it can understand ?
I am using nodejs net module.

I tried many ways but failed.

Comment: Hex is not a primitive but a notation for int with base 16 instead of 10, you can store it as an integer and pass it like that, indeed, an unsigned int max value is 0xFFFFFFFF.

If your device requires an "hex" value, i'd say that any integer between 0x0 and the device's input primitive bit limit should work.